# List comprehension requiring values from seperate lists for function input, with multiple return values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have two lists. One of the lists contains many `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` objects, named `X_train_frames` and the other contains many `pandas.core.series.Series` objects named `y_train_frames`.

Each value in `X_train_frames` maps to a label in `y_train_frames`
I would like to use them in a function together and return a list.

I have tried:

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state = 1, sampling_strategy = 'minority')
X_bal_frames, y_bal_frames = [smote.fit_resample(X_frame, y_frame) for X_frame, y_frame in zip(X_train_frames, y_train_frames)]
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I expect to return two lists of SMOTE resampled data in this case:
`X_bal_frames` will have a list of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`s
and
`y_bal_frames` will have a list of `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `zip(*x)` will return two tuples of a 2D list, each part of the tuple can be saved using the syntax below.

```
a, b = zip(*x)
```

For the case of this example.

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state = 1, sampling_strategy = 'minority')

X_bal_frames, y_bal_frames = zip(*[smote.fit_resample(X_frame, y_frame) for X_frame, y_frame in zip(X_train_frames, y_train_frames)])
```